# How to make Bottom Navigation Bar as used in spotify/ airbnb app?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

I have tried using the android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView and also other libraries for bottom navigation menu but the problem i am facing with all of them is that it cannot show full text size. I cannot manipulate the size of the text also. Is there any solution for this or any other library.

[image]

I want bottom menu like this where you can see the full text and image both at the same time.

Comment: make custom tab layout and place it bottom of screen

Comment: https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

Comment: You can refer https://github.com/pranaypatel512/BottomNavigationView

Comment: @PeDuCKA i have already used this but for more than 3 items the text is not seen full..

Comment: @SurajMakhija but with this i cannot achieve the menu like spotify app

Comment: See this.... https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2016/10/29/android-bottomnavigationview-example/

Comment: bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(120);

Comment: @VikasPatidar this did not help me customize the text size

Comment: @Pravin can you please clarify more what does that do? Does it change the size of the text?

Comment: @bhaskar can you add your code with layout file

Comment: @bhaskar see here https://medium.com/@chornenkyy.v/first-look-at-bottomnavigationview-from-android-design-library-8244de85b953